# vue error Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type. typescript error

Tags: javascript, typescript, forms, vue.js, vuetify.js

**I wonder how can I type the value variable inside data. For I'm getting an error - Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.**

```
<template>
  <v-sheet width="300" class="mx-auto">
      <v-form fast-fail @submit.prevent>
        <v-text-field
          label="First name"
          :rules="firstNameRules"
        >{{ firstName }}</v-text-field>
        <v-btn type="submit" block class="mt-2">Submit</v-btn>
      </v-form>
    </v-sheet>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  data: () => ({
      firstName: '',
      firstNameRules: [
        value  => {
          if (value?.length > 3) return true
          return 'First name must be at least 3 characters.'
        },
      ],
    }),
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you would type any other variable in TypeScript, using the `variable: type` syntax:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    firstName: '',
    firstNameRules: [
      (value: string)  => {
        if (value?.length > 3) return true
        return 'First name must be at least 3 characters.'
      },
    ],
  }),
}
```